# Tried to hide a dock icon but failed

Tags: macos, applications, dock

I tried to hide an app's icon on the dock but the app (Clock) could not be launched.

I googled and found some solutions to dock icon hiding.

I modified the app's Info.plist by adding the following two lines:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

I also tried this:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

But, it didn't work. The app couldn't be launched.
The pop-up window says:

> Clock quit unexpectedly.
>   Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

The app is "Clock" (like the desktop gadget in Win7) that I downloaded from App Store.
http://clock.projectworld.net/

I am wondering whether this app can be modified as an agent or not.

Comment: Can You show us part of the report about what crashed?

Comment: After I modified the app's Info.plist, the app was simply unable to be launched. And a small window popped up saying "Clock quit unexpectedly. Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple." No matter how I tried, the app could not be launched. I could not restore the original Info.plist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the Clock application is code-signed, which is likely what is causing the crash.  I tried to do the same LSUIElement change in the plist file to Clock.app and it gave the same crash.  Some research told me the following:

> There's one more step to the process if the developer has signed the application with an Apple Developer Certificate — and that includes all Mac App Store applications. Without this step, you'll likely get a crash when opening the app. To prevent this, you'll need to re-sign the application using the following command in the Terminal:
>
> sudo codesign -f -s - /path_to_app/appname.app
>
> Replace "/path_to_app/appname.app" with the path and the application name that you just tweaked the Info.plist for. After doing this, press enter, and enter your password. The application will be re-codesigned and you should be able to launch the app without any issues.

source: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/easy_mac_hacks_run_os_x_applications_without_their_dock_icon

I have downloaded Clock.app, Added the LSUIElement key to the plist file, and I resigned the application, and it seems to have had the desired result you are looking for.

There are some considerations though, the only way I could close the app without a dock icon was to use Activity Monitor and kill the process.  The link I pasted above also gives a few more warnings you should read before doing this.

Make a backup, try it out, and let me know if you have the same success I did?

Comment: Although I don't know what "re-sign" really means, I followed the suggestion given. And it worked. Really amazing. But I wonder how long the "re-sign" can last. Is it one-time only? or I have to re-sign the app every time I try to launch it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

.plist files use a key/value format, declaring the type of the key. The correct code is:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>true</string>
```

Stick these in before the `</dict> </plist>` lines, and *voilà*. This works for me on High Sierra. (I am surprised how often faulty code has been suggested here; a moment's perusal of any .plist makes the syntax fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm trying this but I'm still seeing the icon show up